# unresolved external symbol WdmlibIoCreateDeviceSecure referenced in function DriverEntry

Tags: windows, driver

I write a windows 10 driver. And following is the code, actually the code is a sample of a book.

is there anyone know what shold i do to deal with this issue.

```cpp
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <wdmsec.h>

PDEVICE_OBJECT g_cdo = NULL;

const GUID  CWK_GUID_CLASS_MYCDO =
{ 0x17a0d1e0L, 0x3249, 0x12e1, {0x92,0x16, 0x45, 0x1a, 0x21, 0x30, 0x29, 0x06} };

#define CWK_CDO_SYB_NAME    L"\\??\\slbkcdo_3948d33e"

void DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT driver)
{
    // ...
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT driver, PUNICODE_STRING reg_path)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG i;
    UCHAR mem[256] = { 0 };

    UNICODE_STRING sddl = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"D:P(A;;GA;;;WD)");
    UNICODE_STRING cdo_name = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\cwk_3948d33e");
    UNICODE_STRING cdo_syb = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(CWK_CDO_SYB_NAME);

    KdBreakPoint();

    status = IoCreateDeviceSecure(
        driver,
        0, &cdo_name,
        FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN,
        FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN,
        FALSE, &sddl,
        (LPCGUID)&CWK_GUID_CLASS_MYCDO,
        &g_cdo);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        return status;

    // ...
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

the error message is:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol WdmlibIoCreateDeviceSecure referenced in function DriverEntry    MyDriver7   C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\MyDriver7\MyDriver7\Source.obj
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your project with `Wdmsec.lib`.

In Visual Studio, right click the project and go to `Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies` and add `$(DDK_LIB_PATH)Wdmsec.lib`.

Your project file should have something like this added:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Link>
       <AdditionalDependencies>$(DDK_LIB_PATH)wdmsec.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Same applies for the other platforms. This is for `Debug, x64`.